# Have you considered making promotion for Graphic Design StackExchange ?

Tags: discussion, beta

I mean, that would definitely attract more users, and while probably would bring a lot more off topic questions(which would get closed as in any site), would increase also the number of the good ones, and in general, allow the survival of the site.

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't seem to make sense. Search Engine Optimisation is something you do to a site, and I'm pretty sure the SE platform is considered highly optimised. I'm guessing you might mean Search Engine Marketing, i.e target ads in search results.

Comment: Hmmm... Not referring just to html/css, meta tags, etc optimization, internal seo measures. But offsite SEO. Promotion. Generate backlinks, upload to directories, content related portals,twitter, facebook, delicious, stumble upon,blogs, etc, etc. But not doing it for stackexchange as a whole, just for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: That is more promotion than SEO IMO. If that's what you mean, it's a fair question

Comment: I see.. I meant promotion, then  :)

Comment: @S.gfx I recommend changing the question title :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot this one. Change done now.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it really makes sense to promote the site right now, but once we're public and have enough content and traffic, I'm sure Jeff and the team will help us with promotion.

Of course it's up to us to make sure the site reaches that point. Entering private beta doesn't necessarily mean the site will stay alive, we have to bring people in once it goes public, and make sure we make it attractive enough for them.

Answer (score 3):

Advertising the site to print and design professionals and students who might participate in the beta is a good thing at this stage.  Trying to blindly drive up traffic is not helpful at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

It is the job of the community to promote the site heavily through any means necessary so the questions you deem on topic should be promoted. But first it may be necessary to work on the other points :

- [7.9 questions per day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) (15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta)
- [What is on topic](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition)

As described in the guidelines : [The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) one would need to look at

- What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
- How do we promote our site?

You can attain badges by spreading the link for the question as shown below

[image]

Where the link is of the format :
graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/323/**95**
graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/[Post Id]/**[Your User Id]**

The badges available are:

[Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)

Comment: It has dropped to 4.9 questions/day now...